# creating an numpy matrix with a lag

Tags: numpy, matrix, iteration

Lets say I have

```
q=2

y=[5,10,5,15,20,25,30,35,5,10,15,20]

n=len(y)
```

and I want to make a matrix with n x q dimensions where the first row would be [5,10], the second row would be [10,5], and the third would be [5,15] ...etc.

Is there a way to do this or would I have to use a `for loop` and `concatenate` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our good friend index_tricks to the rescue:

```
import numpy as np

#illustrate functionality on a 2d array
y=np.array([5,10,5,15,20,25,30,35,5,10,15,20]).reshape(2,-1)

def running_view(arr, window, axis=-1):
    """
    return a running view of length 'window' over 'axis'
    the returned array has an extra last dimension, which spans the window
    """
    shape = list(arr.shape)
    shape[axis] -= (window-1)
    assert(shape[axis]>0)
    return np.lib.index_tricks.as_strided(
        arr,
        shape + [window],
        arr.strides + (arr.strides[axis],))

print running_view(y, 2)
```

It returns a view into the original array, so O(1) performance.
Edit: generalized to include an optional axis parameter for nd-arrays.

Comment: You got it exactly. Now I have to check out `index_tricks` and try to understand what is happening

Comment: The updated code makes the logic more explicit. as_strided allows you to override the array strides (use with caution; it allows you to create out-of-bounds strides as well). arr.strides + (arr.strides[axis],) tells numpy that a step along the window axis is the same thing as a step along the axis to be viewed; pretty simple. That only leaves some logic to produce a correct shape that does not permit out-of-bound indexing.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; I do insert a new dimension, and it does have an 'arbitrary' and correct stride. Ah I suppose you are replying to my pre-edit post.

Comment: Yes, the first reshape should probably be removed, that is what confused me.

Comment: The first reshape is there merely to illustrate that the function works on more than just 1d arrays

Answer (score -1):

Since NumPy arrays are [row-major ordered](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html) by default, you can directly `reshape()` to "wrap" an array to the rows of a matrix (assuming the number of columns divides the length of the array).

```
import numpy as np

def as_matrix(x, ncols):
    nrows = len(x) // ncols
    return np.array(x).reshape(nrows, ncols)

as_matrix(y, 2)

#> array([[ 5, 10],
#>        [ 5, 15],
#>        [20, 25],
#>        [30, 35],
#>        [ 5, 10],
#>        [15, 20]])
```